# why my request is still pending after resolve?

Tags: reactjs, metamask

hello my react implementation works perfectly on web with metamask extension.
If I use walletconnect ( component web3modal with @walletconnect/web3-provider) and metamask app, I send same commands but something goes wrong.
In particular, when I call something like this

```
try
{
alert('step 1');
await dai.methods.approve(icoquantix_address,amnt).send({from:address,type:type});
alert('step 2');
}
catch(e){ alert(e.message);}
```

As I launch the function, I see alert 'step 1', then I see the approval request on app, but after approval, nothing happens. It seems everything remains stuck. What's happening?
Thank you

Comment: Is the console showing any errors? Also try using console.log instead of alert as it may be possible that while you are interacting with the alert dialog, the response returns and the next alert doesn't show

Comment: no errors in console. even with console.log